# Read / Write NTFS External Hard Disk In Mac Mountain Lion

Tags: mac, hard-drive, ntfs, osx-mountain-lion

I have a 1TB external hard disk which is NTFS formatted and I have some files in that hard disk. When I try to use it in my Mac (Mountain Lion), I get this error:

[image]

I try to use Paragon, NTFS 3G, SL-NTFS but did not show any success and my hard disk still unmounted.

1. How do I solved this issue?
2. After installing the Paragon, NTFS 3G, SL-NTFS (or any other apps), should I do anything else?
3. OR, perhaps this issue comes from my external hard disk itself?

Note: This external hard disk is well readable and writeable in Windows OS.

Comment: Has the drive been properly disconnected in Windows? If you didn't _safely remove_ the drive before disconnecting it in Windows the drive may not be writeable in Mac OS X or Linux.

Comment: is it readable on a ***another*** Windows computer than the one you tested it on?

Comment: Because it gives you the option to initialize the disk, it might be that the partition table is corrupted on that drive. Windows (especially older versions) does not do enough validation of the partition table and can sometimes mount overlapping partitions just fine. Also, Windows XP 32-bit and older cannot understand GPT at all, (they will only use the MBR), so there could be a problem if the disk actually uses GPT but is out of sync with the MBR.

Comment: @speakr properly disconnected. Maybe something is wrong with my partition inside it.

Comment: @Keltari yes. Readable on other machines.

Answer (score 2):

NTFS support on non-Windows systems is notoriously flaky. The only way to know for sure that your disk isn't screwed up is to plug it into a Windows system. And if you *do* have it working with a Windows system, you might as well just network the two computers and [mount the disk over the network](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1568). Simpler, safer.